# GLSL vertex shader crashes computer

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been trying to pinpoint the exact cause of a GLSL shader that crashes my computer. I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2 with a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M. The shader renders correctly but will occasionally crash my computer, drawing regions of black over the display (including outside of the rendering window) until the computer becomes unresponsive.

I receive no errors from `glGetError` and no errors during shader compilation. It appears that the crash no longer occurs when I remove a `uniform mat4` from the vertex shader, such as the model-view matrix, or one of the shadow matrices. Yet according to `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` my graphics card supports 4096 vertex uniform components.

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_halfVec;
varying vec4 v_shadowcoord0;
varying vec4 v_shadowcoord1;
varying vec4 v_shadowcoord2;
varying vec4 v_shadowcoord3;

uniform mat4 mv;
uniform mat3 nmv;
uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix0;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix1;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix2;
uniform mat4 shadowMatrix3;
uniform vec3 lightDir;

void main()
{
    vec4 p4 = vec4(position, 1.0);

    v_texcoord = texcoord;
    v_normal = normalize(nmv * normal);

    vec3 vertexPos = vec3(mv * p4);
    vec3 eyeDir = normalize(-vertexPos);
    v_halfVec = normalize(eyeDir + lightDir);

    v_shadowcoord0 = shadowMatrix0 * p4;
    v_shadowcoord1 = shadowMatrix1 * p4;
    v_shadowcoord2 = shadowMatrix2 * p4;
    v_shadowcoord3 = shadowMatrix3 * p4;

    gl_Position = mvp * p4;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in tracking down the cause of this bug. Thanks!

Comment: The only way that I have experienced crashing of this sort with GLSL is if you haven't bound a buffer to a varying vertex attribute and worth double checking. You may also find luck with tryin gDEBugger http://www.gremedy.com/download.php

Comment: I double-checked and my vertex buffers and attributes appear to be correctly bound. Unfortunately, gDEBugger is not available on this version of Mac OS X, but I have tried OpenGL Profiler. The difficulty is that my system locks up immediately when the bug occurs. I have tried almost identical shaders but without the shadow matrices and coordinates, and they have never crashed.

Comment: This looks like a tricky one, have you tried glGetShaderInfoLog and glGetProgramInfoLog to check for any warnings. it may also be a similar issue to this: http://news.softpedia.com/news/OS-X-10-8-2-Broken-NVIDIA-Drivers-Causing-Pixelmator-to-Crash-312907.shtml

Comment: Both the shader and program info logs are empty, and I'm looking into the NVIDIA driver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an issue in 10.8.2 that has also been seen here: http://news.softpedia.com/news/OS-X-10-8-2-Broken-NVIDIA-Drivers-Causing-Pixelmator-to-Crash-312907.shtml
There should be a Max OS 10.8.3 that will hopefully fix this.

UPDATES: http://www.cultofmac.com/214775/apple-releases-yet-another-10-8-3-os-x-beta-to-developers/

Comment: So far the NVIDIA driver issue in 10.8.2 seems to be the most plausible cause. I'm going to leave the question as unanswered while I look into it more. Thanks for all your help!